# Cannot connect to database url with flyway through Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, flyway

I'm trying to run my flyway migrations, but maven is returning this error of the url config but apparently everything is ok,i tested my application in insomnia (its an API).
i'm using postgreSQL for database.

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:9.16.3:migrate (default-cli) on project demo: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

thats my application.properties:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/candidate
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
```

Im trying to run the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to migrate via maven cli:

*mvn migrate* or something like that.

You application properties are NOT used when doing the migration via the CLI.

For the cli task, you need to supply the variables like this:

```
<plugin>
...
<configuration>
    <user>myUser</user>
    <password>mySecretPwd</password>
    <schemas>
        <schema>schema1</schema>
        <schema>schema2</schema>
        <schema>schema3</schema>
    </schemas>
    <placeholders>
        <keyABC>valueXYZ</keyABC>
        <otherplaceholder>value123</otherplaceholder>
    </placeholders>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/maven/)